# Getting OME while rotating Bitmap

Tags: android

I am trying to rotate Img(Bitmap), by the fallowing code. its working fine up to 5-6 rotations, after that am getting OME?

```
private void rotateImg() {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(curScale, curScale);
    matrix.postRotate(curRotate);
    try {
        temp = Bitmap.createBitmap(temp, 0, 0, temp.getWidth(),
                temp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        setImage.setImageBitmap(temp);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        curRotate = curRotate - 45.0f;
        Toast.makeText( this,"Out Of Memory",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

here "test" is an static bitmap file loaded from SDCard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you creating the bitmap every time? Is there any specific reason? 
If not use the following code:

```
private void rotateImg() {
    int cx = temp.getWidth() / 2;
    int cy = temp.getHeight() / 2;
    matrix.preTranslate(-cx, -cy);
    matrix.postRotate(curRotate);
    matrix.postTranslate(cx, cy);
    setImage.setImageMatrix(matrix);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first answer is probably one potential solution.  The issue here is that you're creating **a lot** of Bitmap objects, which are fairly big, and they're not getting gc'd for whatever reason.

A better solution might be to use a single bitmap, and apply the rotation / scaling when you draw it.  For example, if you were drawing on a `Canvas` that's part of a `View`, rotateImg could simply rotate the matrix and call `invalidate` on the view, and then in the view's `onDraw` method you'd use the `void drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Matrix matrix, Paint paint)` on the canvas to render the bitmap.  Docs are [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20android.graphics.Paint%29).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to use `bitmap.recycle()` method each time you call this method. Try something like this,

```
private void rotateImg() {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(curScale, curScale);
    matrix.postRotate(curRotate);
    try {
         temp.recycle();  //removes the memory occupied by this bitmap object
          temp=null;
        temp = Bitmap.createBitmap(temp, 0, 0, temp.getWidth(),
                temp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        setImage.setImageBitmap(temp);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        curRotate = curRotate - 45.0f;
        Toast.makeText( this,"Out Of Memory",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: but am using that "temp" file in next line to create a new Bitmap, i think we may get some error with this code "trying to use a recycled bitmap"

Comment: oh ok. can you add those lines after  setImage.setImageBitmap(temp); method instead and check.